# How to resolve Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name:length"?

Tags: vb.net, string, substring

```
Dim amountorhour As String = "A4"

If amountorhour.Substring(0, 1) = "A" Then
    amount = amountorhour.Substring(1, amountorhour.Length)--**error comes here**
    HrsWorked = 0
Else
    HrsWorked = amountorhour.Substring(1, amountorhour.Length - 1)
    amount = 0
```

I know this error shows up when I am asking for length of string which is out of range but in this scenario, I don't see anything like that. Please help me in figuring out the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter is the length of the substring from the index that you have specified. So passing `amountorhour.Length` works only if you pass 0 as first parameter which would return the original string.

It seems that you want to take all but the first character, you can use [the overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) with one parameter:

```
amount = amountorhour.Substring(1)
```

This is the same as

```
amount = amountorhour.Substring(1, amountorhour.Length - 1)
```

As an aside, you can use

```
If amountorhour.StartsWith("A") Then
```

instead of

```
If amountorhour.Substring(0, 1) = "A" Then
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, overload method with one parameter worked.